# Creating a table per account

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an SMS gateway with a central price table referenced by all accounts. However, there is a requirement for unique prices for different routes for accounts.

I cannot serve this from the same price table. I was thinking of having a prices table for every account which is created automatically on account creation and specific pricing can be defined for specific account.

Any idea how i can implement this in Ruby on Rails? How can i make sweeping changes accross all tables?
The schema for table looks like this;

```
create_table "prices", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "country"
    t.string   "network"
    t.decimal  "price_euros", :precision => 10, :scale => 3
    t.datetime "created_at",                                 :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                 :null => false
    t.decimal  "price_ugx",   :precision => 10, :scale => 3
    t.decimal  "price_kes",   :precision => 10, :scale => 3
    t.decimal  "price_tzs",   :precision => 10, :scale => 3
    t.decimal  "price_usd",   :precision => 10, :scale => 3
  end
```

Thank you

Comment: Why can't you serve it from the same table?  Anything that can be done with multiple tables having the same schema can be done with one table plus a column holding the erstwhile table name. Then index this column and add a where clause to get the relevant data.  Dynamically creating tables based on app interaction is asking for various kinds of problems.

Comment: @Gene, please elaborate more on this implementation..

Comment: If you will elaborate on your problem.  Is your SMS gateway implemented in Rails?  If so, are the "routes" you refer to Rails routes?  If not, then what is the architecture you have in mind? And what is the basis for claiming "I cannot serve this from the same price table." ?

Comment: Yes, it is implemented in rails with pricing in different currencies chosen according the user currency. So how can i define a price for a particular account as negotiated in the same table?

Comment: @Gene, look at the edit

Comment: @user2963716 why don't you add an accounts table with account_id and use it a foriegn key in this table to reference it?

Comment: @SamD is asking the same question I am.  You didn't answer my question about routes.  What is a route?  Why can't you just tag records with an account id?